# VAR as simultaneous equation model with panel data

Tags: modeling, multivariate-analysis, panel-data, vector-autoregression, simultaneous-equation

Sir
I want to estimate simultaneous equations , where I have industrial analysi equations measuring spillovers from peers to firms and firms to peer simultaneously.Let say , I want to test simulatnaeous equation  where Spillover from Firm A influences Firm B and vice versa

**Y**1=intercept+**β**1**X**1+CONTROL VARIABLES + **ϵ**1

**X**1= intercept +**β**2**Y**1+ CONTROL VARIABLES + **ϵ**2

Can I use structural VAR?equations.which VAR can use for panel data?
I have panel data.
Can anyone suggest how to estimate this model

Comment: What is a 'spillover'? I think if you can explain that domain knowledge to a wider audience, you might get more traction here.

Comment: Spillover is effect of firm on other firm in  group.Let say, it is performance of smaller firm has an influence on larger firm.I want to conduct a size effect study

Comment: would you say that 'spillover' means that performance from last quarter in group a cause a change in performance this quarter in group b? Or does the spillover occur simultaneously? And I assume you measure the performance directly?

Comment: Its a simultaneous equation.The study will consist of five years data yearly. I want to account for both way efect and then compare the effects.It means that equation A  dependent variable is  becoming independent variable in equation B and vice versa.Its like firm A affecting Firm B and  vice versa simultaneously. I  want to compare the influences of both and draw which influence is bigger. i want to estiate both the equations.I HAVE one  exogenous variation to solve  for first equation.but want to estimate both equations.Can  I do with VAR model.My data is panel.so any help???

Comment: do you expect your $\epsilon_i$ to be independent? If so, put $X$ and $Y$ into a vector and then express your equations as a regression. If the error term has covariance, then there will be 'spillover'.

Comment: I expect them to have simultaneouty bias.So I know that we can estimate single equation by simultaneouty model by 2SLS;But I want both B1 AND B2 to compare them later on to determine size effect.How can I handle them?? I mean I WANT to solve both the equations for right hand side

Comment: @ADEEL, consider a structural VAR (SVAR) model. E.g. in R there is a relatively new [`svars`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=svars) package with good documentation and a vignette describing what models you can fit and illustrating the package's functionality with some applications. An older package with SVAR capability is [`vars`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=vars). It also has good documentation and a vignette.